# Compute a multiple integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

A friend of mine asked me to help compute the multiple integral:$$\iint_{(D)} \frac{x^2 y^2}{4+9x^4 y^4}\text{d}\sigma, \ \ D:x^2+y^2\le2.$$ But I find it extremely hard. Is there a simpler way to compute it?

Comment: The Maple code                                                     $$ VectorCalculus:-int(x^2*y^2/(9*x^4*y^4+4), [x, y] = Circle(<0, 0>, sqrt(2)), numeric) $$                      outputs $0.1816728246 $.

Comment: I get 0.18167282790516015` by Mathematica. Slightly different.

Comment: This is only  a question of a given accuracy.

Comment: The answer obtained with Maple is $$ (1/18)*(arctanh(sqrt(3/2)*sqrt(sqrt(13)-3))-arctan(sqrt(3/2)*sqrt(sqrt(13)+3)))*Pi*sqrt(3) $$

Answer (score 2):

I think this is going to be long no matter what you do; however, there is a way that will work, with care. Switch to polar coordinates, and remember the $r \, dr \, d\theta$

Now, any rational function in $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ can be changed to a rational function of a variable $t$ by this trick. Taking $- \pi < \theta < \pi$ and $- \infty < t < \infty,$

$$   \theta = 2 \arctan t $$
$$ \tan \theta = \frac{2t}{1-t^2},  $$
$$ \cos \theta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},  $$
$$ \sin \theta = \frac{2t}{1+t^2},  $$
$$ d \theta  = \frac{2}{1+t^2} \; dt.  $$

Work is then continued with partial fractions.

Editttt; wrote it out. I knew this was stereographic projection, I had details wrong in my mind. Take the point $(0,t)$ on the $y$-axis. Connect it to the point $(-1,0)$ by a line. This line intersects the standard unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in two points, $(-1,0)$ and the point I am calling $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta).$

Comment: Actually, $t=\tan 2\theta $ is better. But I still cannot find an analytical expression.

Comment: @EclipseSun, when writing in that order, $t= \tan (\theta / 2).$ Meanwhile, with a little care, you can do the double integral as iterated integrals in, say, Mathematica,

Comment: Yes. After such transformations we can get an integral of a rational function between $-\infty $ and $+\infty $. And then we can use the knowledge of complex analysis to complete this part. But it is even harder to integrate $r$, isn't it?

Comment: @EclipseSun, I don't really know. I also do not know why you think this is important. My guess it that it is better to integrate $r$ first. Also, with partial fractions, there should be no need for complex analysis.

Comment: If we integrate $r$ first, the transformation above will become useless, since something like $\ln$ and $\sqrt{\sin \theta }$ will appear.

Comment: You do polar, then the transformation, then integrate in the order that makes you happiest.

Comment: It's not a matter of happiness, but of PRACTICABILITY. If we integrate $r$ first, it's impossible to integrate $\theta $, or $t$.